# Use jQuery in a TinyMCE plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

I'm writing a plugin for TinyMCE and I want to use jQuery to do some manipulation on the document being editted.

I'm not looking for a way to use TinyMCE *with* jQuery (e.g. an .tinymce() method on a selector), I know there are solutions for that.

Basically I need to include jQuery in the iframe generated by TinyMCE.

tinymce.dom.ScriptLoader seems to load in the parent window, not in the iframe, so that's not an option.

What I've tried so far:

- Load jquery through ScriptLoader in the parent and plugin context
  (the latter has no effect at all, the former loads it in the wrong context)
- Access window.parent.$, which is undefined (even if it's
  loaded in the parent window)
- RTFM'ing and googling but no relevant hits. If the plugin opens a dialog then there is an option to load additional javascript, but that's also not what I need.

Anyone using jQuery in TinyMCE plugins? How?

**Update / solutution**

Thanks to Thariama's suggestion I was able to get this to work. You can use either an explicit tinymce.get() to get the editor, or the 'ed' instance that's passed to your plugin's init() method. It turns out however that at the init stage itself you cannot (yet) access the parent this way. You can do this in a specific handler.

E.g.

```
(function($) {
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.SOSamplePlugin', {
    init: function(ed, url) {
        $ = ed.getWin().parent.jQuery; // <- WON'T WORK!

        ed.addCommand('soCmd', function(ui, v) {
            if(e = ed.selection.getNode()) {
                $ = ed.getWin().parent.jQuery; // <- WORKS!
                $(e).wrap('<div class="sample" />');
                ed.execCommand("mceRepaint");
            }
        });
        ed.addButton('SO', {
           title: 'Title',
           cmd: 'soCmd',
           image: 'somebutton.png'
        });
    },
    getInfo: function() {
        return {
            longname: 'Example Plugin',
            author: 'Ivo',
            authorurl: 'http://vanderwijk.info/',
            infourl: 'http://vanderwijk.info',
            version: '1.0'
        };
    }
  });
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('so', tinymce.plugins.SOSamplePlugin);
})($);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy

```
var editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
```

jQuery is acessible using

```
editor.getWin().parent.jQuery
```

Comment: thanks! It's the combination of getWin() and/or the appropriate stage when to call it - see update in post.

Comment: Anno 2023 this solution produces an "editor.getWin() is undefined" error unfortunately. It's deprecated in TinyMCE 6.0 and has been marked for removal in TinyMCE 7.0. Use the editor.options.get API instead. [Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editoroptions/)

Answer (score -4):

Well as per my experience says you cannot make any JS or jquery changes to an IFrame, so this thing is not possible.

Comment: you can do basic DOM manupulation in a TinyMCE plugin, I don't see why you can't do that with jQuery

Comment: I have no idea now. But it look like that jQuery build its tree just once, and do not include iframe code.
In fact including jQuery at the begin of the iframe will parse the internal DOM (dom of the iframe), and it works